# Начальное состояние компонента React

Tags: архитектура, redux, reactjs

Есть компонент `ProductList`, который отображает список товаров после загрузки страницы. Но этот список нужно еще получить, сделав запрос по АПИ. Есть сага, которая делает этот запрос и создает действие `show(items)` передавая ему список товаров.

Вопрос в том, где лучше всего запустить начальное действие `init`, которое и подхватит сага?

Сейчас у меня компонент `ProductList` на will mount дергает действие `init`. Но это как-то неправильно. Меня устраивало такое поведение, пока не понадобилось загружать разные списки товаров, в зависимости от условий (например, от URL пути), потому как нужно передавать эти условия в props, а я бы хотел в `ProductList` передавать только одно `props` - `products` уже сформированный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Компонент к приложению подключается при помощи контейнера. Вот в контейнере, например, в методе componentDidMount делаем запрос к АПИ, а результат записываем в state контейнера. При обновлении стейта контейнера, будет обновлен props компонента.

```
class ItemsContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        items: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        api.request().then((items) => (
            this.setState({ items: items })
        ))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ItemsList
                items={this.state.items}
            />
        )
    }
}
```